# Getting 500 error on 13 pages, All Cgi?

Tags: google-search-console, http-code-500, fastcgi

Google Search Console is giving me 500 errors on 13 cgi pages. I'm not sure how to fix. I am using wordpress to design my site. I have opened the error log but I have no idea how to fix. Some of these relate to commerce and sell. We do not sell anything on line. Not sure if I can delete files or if they belong to plug ins and will mess my site up.

Appreciate any help I can get, thanks!

Cgi pages include:

https://micronanalytical.com/cgi-local/mpc

```
-/ctone_process.cgi 
-/ctone_button.cgi 
-/ctone_finder.cgi
-/ctone_bounce.cgi 
-/ctone_customer.cgi 
-/deactivate.cgi 
-/webinfo.cgi
/trigger.cgi /ct_xsell.cgi /rpcdispatch.com 
/PHPMailer_5.2.0/test_script/
```

Comment: A "500 Internal Server" error is a very generic error.   We can't tell you what caused it from the information you provided.  It could be any exception generated by the code that powers those pages.  Anything from a database down, malformed input, or insufficient memory.   Please check your server logs and edit in any specific messages you find so that this can be re-opened.